# For loop Increment with a step not working

Tags: for-loop, go

The following Go program fails  to compile

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
)

func main() {
var celcius int
for i := 0; i <= 300; i + 20 {
    celcius = 5 * (i - 32) / 9
    fmt.Printf("%d \t %d\t \n", i, celcius)
}
}
```

The Error message is "i + 20 evaluated but not used" .  How to give a step increment in golang for loop

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that the result of the expression `i + 20` is not used. One fix is to assign result to `i`:

```
for i := 0; i <= 300; i = i + 20 {
```

A shorter and more idiomatic approach is to use `+=`:

```
for i := 0; i <= 300; i += 20 {
```

Comment: I'm not clear on why/how `i + 20` is "not used" in this case?

Comment: In the question, the result of the expression `i + 20` is not assigned to a variable, nor does it have any side effects.  Therefore, the expression is unused.

Comment: @T3db0t I suspect part of the confusion is that i++ is very common to see as the last expression. i++ is not equivalent to i + 1 it is equivalent to i += 1 or i=i+1